# Menu Bar App Never Becomes Reactivated

Tags: objective-c, macos, menubar, appkit

I'm building a Mac app that only sits in the menu bar with no dock item and no key window and no main menu (it's `LSUIElement` in the info.plist is set to `YES`). When I first launch the app, `applicationDidBecomeActive:` is called, as I expect. However, once another app gains focus, `applicationDidBecomeActive:` is never called again.

This prevents a text field I have within my app from becoming the first responder. When I first open the app, the text field is editable:

[image: before another app gains focus]

But after another app comes to the foreground, the text field is not editable:

[image: after another app gains focus]

#### What I've tried:

When the menu is opened, `menuWillOpen:` is called on the `NSMenu`'s delegate. I've tried placing the following with no success:

```
[NSApp unhide];
[NSApp arrangeInFront:self];
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
[NSApp requestUserAttention:NSCriticalRequest];
[[NSRunningApplication currentApplication] activateWithOptions:NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps];
[[NSRunningApplication currentApplication] unhide];
```

I think the issue is probably related to not having any windows to bring to the front. I feel like I'm grasping at straws here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why should it ever be called again if the app is never relaunched.  If it's in the menubar, doesn't it's process stick around as a sort of quasi-daemon?

Comment: Perhaps it isn't in any way related, but I had a recent issue with iOS not making a view the first responder after a resume event (when it was the first responder prior to the resume). The fix was to resignFirstResponder before sending a becomeFirstResponder message. No idea why, but it got iOS's butt in gear. Perhaps something similar is in play here?

Comment: Hey Ash, the problem may relate to NSMenu. Using it for text input has never been a good idea. Have you tried the same steps with NSWindow?

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is with that how the runloop operates when a `NSMenu` is open, so you should try activating the app before you display the menu. If you're having the `NSStatusItem` display it, I'd suggest doing it yourself like this:

```
- (void)toggleMenu:(id)sender
{
  // App might already be active
  if ([NSApp isActive]) {
    [self.statusItem popUpStatusItemMenu:self.menu];
  } else {
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
  }
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  [self.statusItem popUpStatusItemMenu:self.menu];
}
```

That should work, but I think though in general you'll have better luck with an actual window instead of a menu.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to allow your input to `-becomeFirstResponder`, maybe by overriding `-canBecomeFirstResponder` or by calling the become method yourself.

You'd likely have to implement/call these methods for whatever view is housing your text input, or maybe tell your input view to become the first responder.

Either way, it smells like a responder chain issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `-makeFirstResponder:` on your window. NSWindow is usually the start of the NSResponder chain.

```
- (void)menuWillOpen:(NSMenu *)menu {
    [[NSApp mainWindow] makeFirstResponder:yourTextInputField];
}
```

I'm assuming your text field already accepts first responder since you said your app launches initially with it as the first responder. If not, make sure your text field  overrides `-acceptsFirstResponder:` to return `YES`

```
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```

Edit: Ah, see that you don't have a key window. It looks like NSMenu actually has a window associated with it though, and it's safe to call `-makeFirstResponder:`. Some discussion [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/195835-set-focus-on-nsview-in-an-nsmenuitem.html) suggests overriding `-viewDidMoveToWindow:` on your view containing your text field in the NSMenu like so:

```
- (void)viewDidMoveToWindow {
    [super viewDidMoveToWindow];

    [[self window] makeFirstResponder:yourTextInputField];
}
```